# Would a "reactive force field" be possible?

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, physics

In IRL, reactive armor is a type of armor, that is created to defend the tank from non-explosives kinetic <s>perpetrators</s> penetrators, by **blowing away the projectile** with the detonation of a high explosive.

My idea is to ionize a small portion of air in front of the bullet, then smeck it into the projectile with a strong magnetic field, then repeat this until the bullet stops or reaches you, but with a decreased kinetic energy.

**Would such precise <s>(read:German)</s> system be possible?**

Comment: With all your interest in plasma, maybe you should just [learn magnetohydrodynamics](https://www.ucl.ac.uk/mssl/solar/summerschool13/lectures/MSSL-Arber.pdf).

Comment: @JDługosz The moment when I realized, why XKCD has an [entry](http://badwebcomicswiki.shoutwiki.com/wiki/XKCD) on that wiki.

Comment: What? I don't understand what you're saying.

Comment: https://xkcd.com/1851/ @JDługosz

Answer (score 7):

Sorry, but [Boeing](http://abcnews.go.com/Technology/boeing-patents-star-wars-style-force-field-technology/story?id=29839654) beat you to it.

[image: Boeing's Force Field]

Although it **doesn't** protect you from bullets, it can detect shockwaves from an explosion and ionize air to deflect the shockwave. Here is the video of how this works: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SOmUhjlfh1o

**However,** sorry to pop the excitement, people [doubt that this will even work](https://www.wired.com/2015/03/protect-humans-shockwaves/) as of now it is still only a patent and they *might* haven't build the real thing themselves.

It still looks cool, though.

Comment: @RedactedRedacted thanks for the edit. I don't know there's a "mobile" version by adding m to the end of the filename.

Comment: They always tell me, that plasma bubbles would rapidly expand (just like an explosion) without a magnetic field keeping them together. So, I had the idea to replace the explosion with plasma explosion and add some magnetic assistance to it, for the extra power.